# PostgreSQL - using password/md5 authentication with empty password

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I have the following role in my system:

```sql
CREATE ROLE test LOGIN INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

There is no password. Trying to connect to the db from within the same machine using either psql or PgAdmin3 to the above role I'm getting:

```
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

When the password is set I can connect perfectly.

The `pg_hba.conf` is default - merely:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

[Create Role statement help](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createrole.html) says:

> `PASSWORD password`
>
> Sets the role's password. (A password is only of use for roles having the LOGIN attribute, but you can nonetheless define one for roles without it.) If you do not plan to use password authentication you can omit this option. If no password is specified, the password will be set to null and password authentication will always fail for that user. A null password can optionally be written explicitly as PASSWORD NULL.

Can I deduct from that that having a NULL password password authentication will always fail? Is this also the case for MD5 authentication? Is there anyway to connect using an NULL password role without specifying `trust` authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed an empty password is equivalent to no password so it's not going to be accepted by the server when `pg_hba.conf` says that a password is required.

Still, there are various ways to avoid inputting the password:

- `trust` method in `pg_hba.conf`, possibly constrained to a specific user and database
- client-side `PGPASSWORD` environment variable
- client-side [.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file
- dummy password like "test" stored in the same place than the login name

Comment: Thanks! I don't mind to input password when there is one, I just look into a way of connecting when there is no password at all...

Comment: I believe adding `trust` entries for these users is the only way

Comment: @Vic: Well, there are also the [`ident` and `peer` authentication methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) but those, too, are only for trusted clients ...